# How do you breed an Ash dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

I just saw a new dragon in the marketplace called an Ash dragon. How do I breed one, and what is the breeding time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Dragonvale Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Ash_Dragon) you can breed an Ash Dragon by breeding a Plant Dragon with a Lightning Dragon, or by breeding any plant hybrid with any lightning hybrid.

The breeding time is 6 hours, or 4 hours 48 minutes with the improved breeding cave/EBI.  It is not a limited dragon.

Answer (score 0):

The cactus dragon is leaf and lightning but the ash is lightning and leaf. For ash breed lightning on the left and leaf on the right

Comment: I did this and got it first time!

Comment: You were just lucky I think.  There has been a lot of study to prove that breeding order has no effect on hybrids - but welcome to Arqade, and thanks for sharing your experience!